# Cambiar Nombre desde una lista csv con python

Tags: python, imagen, csv

Antes me presento ya que  soy nuevo por aquí y apenas voy iniciando con esto.
Lo que quiero resolver es lo siguiente, tengo diferentes carpetas con imágenes etiquetadas de la siguiente manera Nombre apellido Paterno Apellido Materno y fecha de nacimiento ejemplo: **luís Pedro de la rosa fuentes 14.02.1986** he logrado hacer un scrip que me trae los nombres de los archivos y guardarlos en un csv, ahora quisiera saber si puedo separar el nombre de la fecha para ponerlos en una columna diferente, y así tener el nombre y fecha de nacimiento por separado, para después leer el csv y conectarme a la base de datos buscar por nombre y fecha de nacimiento y me regrese el numero de empleado generando o generando el csv con los campos nombre, fecha y numero para después ir a la base de datos a la tabla fotos buscar el numero de empleado y subir su foto, tomar el  id de la foto y escribirla en otra tabla que hace referencia, espero puedan apoyarme o guiarme con sus  comentarios

gracias
saludos!

Comment: Te recomiendo ampliamente que agregues tu codigo actual, asi sera mas facil que obtengas una buena respuesta a tu problema actual

Comment: 'import os
import csv
path = '/home/Document/Fotos/'
lstFiles = []
lstDir = os.walk(path) 
for root, dirs, files in lstDir:
    for fichero in files:
        (nombreFichero, extension) = os.path.splitext(fichero)
        if (extension == ".JPG"):
            lstFiles.append(nombreFichero+extension)
            print (nombreFichero+extension)
            pass
        pass
    pass
print('listado Finalizado')
print "longitud de la lista = ", len(lstFiles)
with open('filename', 'wb') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting = csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    wr.writerow(lstFiles)'

Comment: Te sugiero que agregues el código como parte de la pregunta, es tan sencillo como hacer click en  [edit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurren dos formas de recuperar fecha y nombre, obviamente funcionana si en todos los casos tenemos un formato similar a esto `<nombre y apellido> <dd>.<mm>.<aaaa>`

En primer lugar podemos establecer que la fecha son los últimos 10 caracteres, por lo que obtener ambos campos se podría resolver con un "slice", de la siguiente forma:

```
text = "luís Pedro de la rosa fuentes 14.02.1986"

nombre = text[:-10]
fecha = text[-10:]

print("nombre: {}".format(nombre))
print("fecha : {}".format(fecha))

> nombre: luís Pedro de la rosa fuentes 
> fecha : 14.02.1986
```

La otra forma es un poco más compleja pero más flexible y es usando expresiones regulares:

```
import re

m=re.search(r'^(.*?)(\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4})', text)
print("nombre: {}".format(m.group(1)))
print("fecha : {}".format(m.group(2)))

> nombre: luís Pedro de la rosa fuentes 
> fecha : 14.02.1986
```

Comment: Buenas No entendi  aunque  ise  unos intentos, lo que  tengo es una archivo csv con este formato     "CRUZ MARTINEZ BRUNO 06.10.83.JPG","GUANI GARCIA JUANA MARIA 08.03.82.JPG","CAMPOS VILLEGAS MARCO ANTONIO 31.03.82.JPG","FELIX SANTOS YADIRA 13.05.90.JPG","SAUCEDO BLANCO DIEGO EDUARDO 25.12.88.JPG"  la idea es leer el csv que so lo hago de la siguinete manera         
'archivo = open("filename.csv", "r")
for linea in archivo.readline():
    print linea' . ahora  quiero  optener es "CRUZ MARTINEZ BRUNO", "06.10.83" ".JPG"

Comment: @BernardinoHernándezHernández: Con el primer método que puse en mi respuesta, si haces `linea[:-10]`  obtienes el nombre completo y `linea[-10:]` debieras obtener la fecha, pruebalo y cualquier cosa me dices.

Comment: Gracias, he  logrado un avance con tu  ayuda, esto es lo que  llevo fichero = open('filename.csv', 'rb')
contenido = fichero.read()
filas = contenido.replace('"', '').replace('\r', '').split(',')
for fila in filas:
    nombre = fila[:-13]
    fechana= fila[-12:-4]
    images = fila[-3:]
    print ("nombre: {}".format(nombre))
    print ("fechana: {}".format(fechana))
    print ("images: {}".format(images))
fichero.close()